# How to concatenate two string in Dart?

Tags: string, dart

I am new to Dart programming language and anyone help me find the best string concatenation methods available in Dart.

I only found the plus (+) operator to concatenate strings like other programming languages.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There are 3 ways to concatenate strings

```
String a = 'a';
String b = 'b';

var c1 = a + b; // + operator
var c2 = '$a$b'; // string interpolation
var c3 = 'a' 'b'; // string literals separated only by whitespace are concatenated automatically
var c4 = 'abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh' 
         'abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh abcdefgh';
```

Usually string interpolation is preferred over the `+` operator.

There is also [StringBuffer](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html) for more complex and performant string building.

Comment: Actually you don't have to separate adjacent string literals with space. 'hello ''world' will be printed as hello world

Comment: the + operator is a bad practice for string concatenation, see: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#prefer-using-interpolation-to-compose-strings-and-values

Comment: If you need string interpolation with accessing properties or even methods - put content into curly braces like here (I usually use this approach for logs): "${assets[index].size.width.toStringAsFixed(0)}x${assets[index].size.height}"
It could have output like this:
1000x2000.0

Comment: I know string interpolation is preferred but when I have two String literals which are looked up from a `Map<dynamic, String>` where the dynamic is an enum, Dart screams "unnecessary string interpolation" in VSCode and when I switch to `+` the red underline is gone and it stops shouting at me.

Comment: Also Iterable.join() can be used to concatenate Strings

Answer (score 10):

If you need looping for concatenation, I have this :

```
var list = ['satu','dua','tiga'];
var kontan = StringBuffer();
list.forEach((item){
    kontan.writeln(item);
});
konten = kontan.toString();
```

Comment: It would be better to use `writeAll` when using iterables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68284916/2411667

Answer (score 10):

Suppose you have a Person class like.

```
class Person {
   String name;
   int age;

   Person({String name, int age}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

And you want to print the description of person.

```
var person = Person(name: 'Yogendra', age: 29);
```

Here you can concatenate string like this

```
 var personInfoString = '${person.name} is ${person.age} years old.';
 print(personInfoString);
```

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way

```
String get fullname {
   var list = [firstName, lastName];
   list.removeWhere((v) => v == null);
   return list.join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The [answer by Günter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53626950/2411667) covers the majority of the cases of how you would concatenate two strings in Dart.

If you have an Iterable of Strings it will be easier to use `writeAll` as this gives you the option to specify an optional separator

```
final list = <String>['first','second','third'];
final sb = StringBuffer();
sb.writeAll(list, ', ');
print(sb.toString());
```

This will return

> 'first, second, third'

Answer (score 1):

**Let's think we have two strings** 
String a = 'Hello';
String b = 'World';
String output;

**Now we want to concat this two strings**

output = a + b; 
print(output);

```
Hello World
```