# Append to String or var in Dart

Tags: dart

When I want to append to a string or var in PHP I use:

```
value = "this one";
value .= " and that one";
```

How do I do this in Dart? I can't find the correct documentation to tell me this.

I'm literally just after knowing the correct operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there are multiple ways to do that. If you want code which looks like PHP you can do this:

```
var value = "this one";
value += " and that one";
```

Else, you can use some of the recommendations from:
[How to concatenate two string in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53626923/how-to-concatenate-two-string-in-dart)