# How to combine two patterns in Dart?

Tags: regex, datetime, dart, concatenation, iso

In Dart, a `Pattern` is "an interface for basic searches within strings" as it says in the doc.

I wanted to combine two `Pattern`s like so:

```
const Pattern REGEX_DATETIME_WITHOUT_TIMEZONE = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.(\d{3}|\d{6}))?';
const Pattern REGEX_DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE = r'$REGEX_DATETIME_WITHOUT_TIMEZONE[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}';
```

But that `$` syntax to inject variables cannot be used in `Pattern`s. So which would be the most reasonable way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because the use of raw strings here makes this *slightly* different, especially since usually string interpolation is preferred over concatenating with `+`.

Comment: **A duplicate of [How to concatenate two string in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53626923/how-to-concatenate-two-string-in-dart)** because the only problem in this question is string interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

> But that `$` syntax to inject variables cannot be used in `Pattern`s.

`Pattern` is the abstract base class for `String` and for `RegExp`.  What you have are two `String` literals that are being used to initialize two variables with the static type of `Pattern`.  Their actual type is still `String`.

What prevents you from using `$` to do string interpolation is that you're using *raw strings* (indicated by the `r` prefix to your string literals), which inherently treat all characters (other than a closing quote) literally.

You could just use normal string concatenation to combine your strings:

```dart
const String REGEX_DATETIME_WITHOUT_TIMEZONE = r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.(\d{3}|\d{6}))?';
const String REGEX_DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE = REGEX_DATETIME_WITHOUT_TIMEZONE + r'[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}';
```

If concatenation is onerous and you really want interpolation, then you can store your raw strings in intermediate variables and then use interpolation to combine them:

```dart
const String REGEX_TIMEZONE = r'[+-]\d{2}:\d{2}';
const String REGEX_DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE = '$REGEX_DATETIME_WITHOUT_TIMEZONE$REGEX_TIMEZONE';
```

Presumably you later want to construct actual `RegExp` objects from them:

```dart
final regExpWithoutTimeZone = RegExp(REGEX_DATETIME_WITHOUT_TIMEZONE);
final regExpWithTimeZone = RegExp(REGEX_DATETIME_WITH_TIMEZONE);
```

Finally, I feel compelled to note that the current Effective Dart style recommendation is to [not use all-caps for constants](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#prefer-using-lowercamelcase-for-constant-names).